# Does the Joule-Thomson effect violate the Ideal gas laws?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, volume

I've got a question that's been baffling me. Does the "Joule-Thomson's effect", in which the temperature drops when the gas passes through a valve, violate the Ideal gas laws, which state that temperature and volume are directly proportional? Or does this have something to do with adiabatic processes? Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Ideal gases do not show the Joule Thomson effect. It is due to long range interactions between the gas molecules, and no such interactions exist in an ideal gas.

Comment: Good idea, that's why we keep the joule's coefficient thing as zero for ideal gas :P

Answer (score 3):

For an ideal gas, the temperature would not change, and the volume increase would be exactly offset by a pressure decrease, such that Pv = constant.

The JT effect is the result of deviation from ideal gas behavior.  Here, the specific enthalpy is a function not only of temperature but also pressure.

Comment: But when the ideal gas expands suddenly, wouldn't it expand using it's internal energy, this would cause a decrease in internal energy, which would decrease it's temperature right? I don't understand why ideal gases don't show this effect?

Comment: There are two things happening.  Yes, the gas internal energy is decreasing due to expansion cooling, but it also increasing due to irreversible viscous heating.  For an ideal gas, these two effects cancel one another.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as an ideal gas. All gases exhibit non-ideal behavior. Real gases change to a liquid or solid form at sufficiently low temperatures, and lose electrons to become a plasma at sufficiently high temperatures. Ideal gases (which don't exist) do not do that. The Joule-Thomson effect is another way that real gases exhibit a deviation from ideal behavior.

When you see the word "law" used in physics, it is best to translate that as "an equation that is sometimes useful". Ohm's Law, Newton's Laws of Motion, Kepler's Laws, and the Ideal Gas Laws: None of these are universally true. They are however approximately true and highly useful under some conditions.